# I have Python installed, but gcc cant find Python.h

Tags: python, c++, gcc

I'm trying to build python modules with c++, but every time I try to build something I get an error of

> fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Here is the what I run:

> gcc -Wall -I /usr/lib/python3.8 hello.cpp -o hello.so

I located the Python.h file in my usr/include/python3.8 directory, and also running locate Python.h in shell finds it as expected.

I have installed python3-dev and tried reinstalling it also.
It is the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2)

Comment: See if the file exists here: `ls -al /usr/include/python3.8/Python.h`

Comment: Don't you mean -I /usr/include/python3.8 instead of -I /usr/lib/python3.8?

Comment: @AnonMail oh, my bad, yeah i do mean /usr/include/python3.8